# How should a `FormType` be structured in order to include an `EntityType` field which doesn't exist in the `FormType` entity?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Taking the below as an example, OrderType is based on the entity <kbd>Order</kbd>. The form that is required needs to contain the following two EntityType dropdowns within it:

- <kbd>Category</kbd> (this does not exist in `Order` - it is just to subset the dropdown of `Product` to make it more manageable)
- <kbd>Product</kbd>

The identifying Category variables (`Category_id` and `CatName`) only exists within the <kbd>Product</kbd> entity (the Order can include multiple <kbd>Product</kbd>s) and as a result, Symfony throws back an error saying:

> Neither the property "category_id" nor one of the methods "getcategory_id()", "category_id()", "iscategory_id()", "hascategory_id()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Order".

**Is there a way that this `Category` field can be included even though it doesn't exist in the Order entity?**

It doesn't seem right to add `category_id` to the <kbd>Order</kbd> entity. I was thinking of something along the lines of below using `'mapped'=>'false'` but I can't get it to work:

```
    $builder
        ->add('category_id','entity',array(
            'class'=>'AppBundle:Product',
            'placeholder' => '-- Choose --',
            'choice_label'=>'CatName',
            'mapped'=>'false',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('p');
            }))
```

...and then after an Ajax response, feed in the category back in with `$category`?

```
        ->add('products','entity',array(
            'class'=>'AppBundle:Order',
            'placeholder' => '-- Choose --',
            'choice_label'=>'ProductName',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er, $category ) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->where('p.category_id = :id')
                    ->setParameter('id', $category )
                    ->orderBy('p.ProductName','ASC');
            }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, adding a Category property to the Order entity just for forms is less than ideal.  What I would do is make a OrderCategoryType and pass in Order and Category as an array.

```
// Controller
$order = new Order();
$category = new Category();  // Or create from $order->getProduct()
$data = ['order' => $order, 'category' => $category);

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
  ->add('order',new OrderType(),
  ->add('category',new CategoryType()
);
```

You will have to do some messing around to keep everything in sync but it should work just fine.