# Symfony2-Fields from multiple entites in a single form

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities Employee and EmployeeJob. I want to make a single form using fields from both entities. I have already made the corresponding form types for both the entities using doctrine form generator. Individually, both the forms re working fine. I want to combine them into a single form. I had gone through so many websites and I dont find the following piece of code useful which returns multiple form types from  the controller

```
return array(
            'form1' => $form->createView(),
            'form2'   => $form->createView(),
        );
```

Comment: If the two entities are independent then this will apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077783/how-should-a-formtype-be-structured-in-order-to-include-an-entitytype-field/34091003#34091003.  But I am fairly certain then you want an embedded form.  It's possible you may need to set the cascade_validation option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138505/symfony2-validation-not-working-for-embedded-form-type

Answer (score 0):

Have a glance to Embedded Forms: `http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms`

Comment: I'm able to embed multiple forms inside another form.But the validations are not working, which actually works individually using annotations.