# How can I add to my form one field from entity that it's not mapped from main entity

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like know if is possible to add my form a field that it's not passed with referenced. This is code:

RetiroResiduo Entity:

```
class RetiroResiduo
{

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\SolicitudRetiroBundle\Entity\SolicitudRetiro")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="numeroSolicitudRet_id", onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="numeroSolicitudRet")
    */

    protected $numeroSolicitudRet;

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GestionResiduos\ResiduoBundle\Entity\Residuo")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="siglaRepresentativa_id", onDelete="CASCADE",referencedColumnName="siglaRepresentativa")
    */

    protected $siglaRepresentativa;
```

Residuo Entity:

```
class Residuo
{
/**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\column(type="string", length=6) 
    */      
    protected $siglaRepresentativa;

    /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    * @ORM\column(type="string", length=150) 
    */
    protected $nombreResiduo;
```

my form is:

```
class RetiroResiduoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('siglaRepresentativa')
     ....
```

So, siglaRepresentativa in my form is shows select dropdown and only have 3 characters. I would like to show the field nombreResiduo from Residuo Entity instead. I am new in symfony and probably this is solved easily. I hope your advices! grettings

Comment: Perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077783/how-should-a-formtype-be-structured-in-order-to-include-an-entitytype-field/34091003#34091003.  Instead of a second entity it would just be single value but the concept og using an array is the same.

Comment: I would really recommend to rename the field "siglaRepresentativa" in the "Residuo" entity to "id", even if it's a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label for docs.

```
$builder->add('siglaRepresentativa', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'YourBundle:Residuo',
    'choice_label' => 'nombreResiduo',
));
```